# Chrome extension alerts made from content script vanish without interaction

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, alert

My content.js is effectively

```
//do stuff
//if certain stuff then
alert('blahblahblah');
```

I find that the alert pops up, but sometimes it vanishes right away. How can I made it require a click to dismiss? Or debug why exactly this is happening?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the browser. I know that these modal dialogs are being reworked to become less blocking of the entire browser UI.

Comment: hm, in that case I might need to rework it to display the alert AND insert a banner on to the page as well. All I need is for it to block that page, not the entire browser.

Comment: You can try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Please describe things like how often it happens, under what conditions, etc. You've basically given us very little to duplicate the issue.

Comment: I don't have such an example because it only happens sometimes and I don't know of any triggers. I'm asking what I can use to figure out why it is happening.

Comment: There's not much that would be relevant before the alert line, it's fetching a page and checking the value of the response, but that's all working fine because the alert does happen. It's what happens after the alert shows up that's the issue.

Comment: It seems to happen maybe 10-20% of the time.